# Shell script for running g++

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, g++

I don't know too much about scripts but I need a script that will run this command:

```
g++ -O0 -c fileName.cpp && nm fileName.o | egrep ' [A-Z] ' | egrep -v ' [UTV] ' | grep -v .eh > fileName.txt
```

for files with names `000000 - 008577`. So how should my script be written?

UPD2:
I've written a script and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="g++ -O0 -c "
s2=".cpp && nm "
s3=".o | egrep ' [A-Z] ' | egrep -v ' [UTV] ' | grep -v .eh >> "
s4=".txt"

for ((i=0; i<=8577; i++)) do
    num="$( printf '%06d' ${i})"
    s="${s1}${num}${s2}${num}${s3}${num}${s4}"
    eval $s
done
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please read.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="g++ -O0 -c "
s2=".cpp && nm "
s3=".o | egrep ' [A-Z] ' | egrep -v ' [UTV] ' | grep -v .eh >> "
s4=".txt"

for ((i=0; i<=8577; i++)) do
    num="$( printf '%06d' ${i})"
    s="${s1}${num}${s2}${num}${s3}${num}${s4}"
    eval $s
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces around the equal sign when you get to num and s.